# Advice for Beginner in Wordpress

Tags: web-services

I am very new to the wordpress. My simple objective is i want to create one website with database. I have donwloaded wordpress. After this how should i start installing and configuring my local setup before uploading my site into a webserver. Please help.

Regards
Dinesh.

Comment: U can get a lot of help just reviewing the wordpress page [http://codex.wordpress.org/Getting_Started_with_WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Getting_Started_with_WordPress)

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Just install WordPress.

Comment: Here you can find a step by step tutorial on installing wordpress tutorial http://www.shartd.com/wordpress/basic-wordpress-tutorial/how-to-install-wordpress/ This site contains some other tutorials on installing wordpress theme, adding page etc

Answer (score 1):

Download XAMPP or WAMP and take some time to get familiar with it (it will set up a web server on your computer).

You'll have to copy the WordPress folder into the www/ or htdocs/, access it from your browser and start the WordPress installation.

Most likely, you'll want to make a custom theme for your WordPress installation. See here for more details: http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development